# Night mode image processing

Tags: image-processing

We have an internal application that displays multipage TIFFs (scanned product documentation) as a list of images (a basic document viewer).

Now we have the request to implement a night mode when displaying the TIFF pages. At first I thought that night mode is simply a negative image but it seems it is not so simple.

Is there a documented image processing algorithm that generates a night mode version of a given image (in my situation the image contains text plus images)?  Or each developer implements its own method?

Answer (score 0):

Typically, "Night Mode" means changing the white balance or color temperature of an image to a warmer color (with more reds) versus a cooler color (with more blues). Here's a [link](https://softwarebydefault.com/2013/04/11/bitmap-color-balance/) to some C# code on changing the color balance.

Comment: I tried this but it did not work me. White pages remained white no matter the color adjustment I tried.

Comment: Since you're probably working with only black and white images, you may want to take a different approach than color temperature. You could just change all the white pixels to a warm sepia-like color for display. This link has some c# sepia code and a link to a sample from Microsoft https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19542174/changing-images-in-the-picturebox-to-sepia.

Comment: I stumbled upon this project and thought about your question. https://github.com/Tyrrrz/LightBulb . It works just like NightMode and is a clone/reimplementation of f.lux, the original display changer.  This app takes a different approach than what I suggested by changing the monitor instead of changing the images. It should be very interesting for what you're trying to do. Good luck!